# Two buttons side by side, if one is removed the other fills 100% width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I am using Bootstrap and I know how to make the buttons appear side by side but having issues achieving what I want.

When the buttons are side by side in a 100% width container everything is fine.  However, if the second button is removed I would like the first button to fill 100%.

Is there a CSS only approach?

Comment: Please share waht you have tried so far ?

Comment: Can you clarify *However, if one of those buttons are gone I would like the other button to fill 100%.*. Do you have an example we can look at?

Comment: I've provided a visual example.

Comment: Can you provide the css which you have tried?

Comment: Why can't you use PHP if->else to generate different bootstrap classes depending on the case?

Comment: Still don't know what you mean by `gone`. Gone like how? When screen resizes? Hover? Or if you just simply remove the second button from the markup?

Comment: Are you open to a flexbox solution? Minimal code, effective and modern layout technique. Only possible drawback is [no IE 8 & 9 support](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex).

Comment: I went with only-child psuedo. It seemed to work ok in IE8 and up.  Flex would be awesome if they ever decided to provide browser support for IE8 and up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS only solution would be to use `only-child` pseudo selector

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  width: 340px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  padding: 5px;
}

.btn {
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  background: #5d4ca5;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  width:157px;
  display: inline;
}

.container .btn:only-child {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="btn">Button One</button>
  <button class="btn">Button Two</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <button class="btn">Button One</button>
</div>
```

See the working Fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/sjpx5c34/1/ (remove the second button and your only button will have 100% width.)

Comment: I was fiddling with this right before you posted it and it's essentially what I went with.  Kudos to you!

Answer (score 5):

> When the buttons are side by side in a 100% width container everything
>   is fine. However, if one of those buttons are gone I would like the
>   other button to fill 100%.
>
> Is there a CSS only approach?

Yes. You can easily accomplish this with the [`flex-grow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) property of [**CSS Flexbox**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow):

> The `flex-grow` CSS property specifies the flex grow factor of a flex
>   item. It specifies what amount of space inside the flex container the
>   item should take up.

Basically, you can tell an element to take up all available width. So if there are two elements, they will share the space equally. If one element is removed, the other expands to fill the width.

Here's all the code you need to make this work:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <button type="button">Button 1</button>
    <button type="button">Button 2</button>
</div>
```

**CSS** (relevant parts)

```
#container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
}

button {
   flex-grow: 1; /* this one line tells button to stretch across all available width */
}
```

DEMO (click buttons for effect): http://jsfiddle.net/rjy6nvj2/1/

*Note: Flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex).*

Comment: Great solution but only for modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Trick named `display:table-cell`:

```css
div { width:300px; border:1px solid; display:table; }
div > span { display:table-cell; border:1px solid red; width:50%; }
```

```html
<div>
  <span>First</span> 
  <span>Second</span>
</div>

<div>
  <span>First</span> 
</div>
```

Comment: I always forget about table-cell.  However sometimes the button titles are longer than one another and if they are it expands the cell larger than one another.

Answer (score -1):

**Anthony Russo** Hi there.

This code below will show how to first **center** what and when you need to center.
Because you have a reason why one button will be removed.
I set up a little sample jquery to remove the Second Button when you mouse over it, for this example.

When you mouse over, it also adds the class `centerthis` to the First Button to center it.

Hope this helps to get you started.

**Updated**
I see you have added to your post, so I have made added a small change to the my code.

When you have the second button removed, you also want the remaining button width to go 100%.
My code now does this for you too.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Remove button and center</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.spacer {
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}       
.block {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: darkorange;
} 
.block3 {
  height: 40px;
  width:550px; 
  padding-top: 3px;  
  background-color: blueviolet;
}     
.centerthis {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;  
}
.remove-on-hover {
  display: none;
}
.change-width {
 width: 100%;
}     
</style>

</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top ">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container col-lg-12 spacer"></div>
    
    
    
<div class="container col-lg-12 block">
    
    <div class="col-sm-6 block3 centerthis">
          <div class="col-xs-6 centerthis"  >
           <div type="text" id="firstbutton" class="col-xs-6 btn btn-warning">First Button</div>
       
           <div type="text" id="whenchanged" class="col-xs-6 btn btn-warning">Second Button</div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
   
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
<script>
jQuery(function () {
    var myMenu = $('#whenchanged');
    myMenu.mouseenter(function () {
 
        $('#firstbutton').addClass("centerthis change-width");
        $("#whenchanged").addClass("remove-on-hover");
    });
})    
    
</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

[image]